# How do I allow regular non-admin users to view other users' emails?

Tags: 8, users, emails

Email is now an included field in core, but the stock email for users seems to be set to private; only users with administrator privileges or the user themselves can see.

I'd like to allow other users to see this basic field, without having to create yet another email field where someone has to copy the information over from the other other simply for the ability for it to be visible.

This should be a fairly easy/common practice, but I can't find anything yet.

How do I allow regular non-admin users to view other users' emails?

Comment: In 15 years of developing for the web, I've literally never once been on a website where people's email addresses are made public. I wouldn't consider this to be common practice at all, might be why you're struggling to find an existing solution. Altering the access of that element in whatever context(s) you need is probably quite straight forward with code, but where should users be "seeing" this information? On the profile page with other fields for example?

Comment: The fact the email is not visible to other users is simply to avoid spamming. Also, it is a bad idea to show the email used to create an account. I agree with @Clive tha showing the email address is not such a common practice.

Comment: I do not want to make users' email fields available to the general public. But, in my 12 years of working with several federal departments, a host of NGOs, and numerous school systems - I can assure you it is very common practice to make your colleagues' general contact information, including their primary email, available to other authenticated users.

If your case is that the standard method for providing this email is as a separate entity than the user's registered account email, I can accept that - though it seems a bit unnecessarily redundant for a closed system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar use case. Here's another solution:
I added a new email field to users' profiles, and in a custom module (I did this is Drupal v8.1), use `hook_user_presave`[See Drupal Api](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/drupal%21core%21modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_presave/8):

`function MYMODULE_user_presave(User $user){
    $user->set('field_profile_email', $user->getEmail());
}`

Then you can use this new field in Views, for example, in a department contact list, as was mentioned in a comment to the question. You could use [Field Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) to further enhance this as well.

This does have the downside of creating a second field, but the function avoids having to manually copy it, and it's now available anywhere.

Comment: this will copy the email once it's saved or updated but will not copy it if it already exists in the email field, right ?

Comment: Correct. This wouldn't affect any users already in the database. To do that, you'd need resave them.

Answer (score 7):

One route you can take is to allow users the *View user information* permission and display this information on the user profile page.

To do so, override **[user.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!user!templates!user.html.twig/8.2.x)** in your theme (copy it from **core/modules/user/templates/user.html.twig** to your theme's template directory) then inject the email into the template via [`hook_preprocess_user()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21user.module/function/template_preprocess_user/8.2.x) in your **mytheme.theme** file:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_user()
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_user(&$variables) {
  $variables['mail'] = $variables['user']->getEmail();
}
```

In this example, you'll be able to user `{{ mail }}` to insert the email variable into your user profile template.

Comment: Thanks, that works great! Is there a way to enable the email field to show using views, though? The user directory is the primary way users look up contact information.

Comment: The equivalent workaround for views would be something like [hook_preprocess_views_view_field](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!views!views.theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_views_view_field/8.2.x) to inject the user email into your views field.

Comment: $variables['user']->getEmail(); this returns only currently logined users email.

Answer (score 0):

There is a D8 Vore feature request to add a permission to see other users' mail address: [Add new permission to view user email field [#2799049] \| Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2799049)