# Display Users emails with views

Tags: views, 8

I want to display the users emails with views, but it doesn't show for the users, only the administrators can see them.

How can i display them to the users with views, and i have a warning: Email address for a given user. This field is normally not shown to users, so be cautious when using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do it by using user_presave, i created a field_profile_email field using this answer : https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/205308/65949